# GCP Artefact registry does not allow sub directories to organise the images dev,prod etc

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-container-registry, google-artifact-registry

We are planning to move to the GCP artefact registry from Google Container registry however we have observed that there is no provision to create or push images to subfolders.

For example:
I need to push dev images to

Dev:

us-central1-docker.pkg.dev/myproject/myrepo/dev/app1:1.1

us-central1-docker.pkg.dev/myproject/myrepo/dev/app2:1.2

Prod:

us-central1-docker.pkg.dev/myproject/myrepo/prod/app2:1.2

us-central1-docker.pkg.dev/myproject/myrepo/prod/app2:1.2

I see artefact registry does not allow this and would need to create multiple repositories and have images just inside that, which means too many repos and apparently difficult to manage.

Is there any way to manage docker images exactly like gcr ?

if i push images with folder path ,artefact registry takes the "foldername/image" as the complete image name, which was not the case with GCR.

Ideally, there should be a folder with name dev, prod and images should be pushed inside it.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Because it's not possible to create folder on GCR or Artifact registry, it's fine that you can't.

In fact, you have only an image name in your registry. If your image name contain / by convention the console present this as folders (same things with Cloud Storage).

Name correctly your image name with your "folder" path, and push them. It will work.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @guillaume. However, there is the difference if i push images with folder path ,artefact registry takes the "foldername/image" as the complete image name. Ideally, there should be a folder with name dev, prod and images should be pushed inside it. I have updated my answer with the screenshot.

Comment: Maybe a UI glitch/bug. It should be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want separate repositories for dev/prod. You can then set up different permissions on those repositories. Repositories effectively act as folders to store collections of images.

Alternatively, you can always tag any image with whatever name you want. e.g.

myrepo/dev/image/name
myrepo/prod/image/name

And push them to AR

Comment: No, i does not work, if you try this you would not get subfolders with the name as dev or prod instead you will see image with name as dev/image/name:tag under myrepo. Please refer the screenshot i shared in my question above.